# Problems parsing a JSON which is read from a URL

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, urllib2, simplejson

I'm having a problem that I believe has a simple solution.

I'm writing a Python script which reads a JSON string from a URL and parses it.  To do this I'm using urllib2 and simplejson.

The problem I'm having has got to do with encoding.  The URL I'm reading from does not explicitly state in which encoding it is (as far as I can tell) and it returns some Icelandic characters.  I cannot give out the URL I'm reading from here, but I've set up a sample JSON data file on my own server and I'm also having problems reading that.
Here is the file: http://haukurhaf.net/json.txt

This is my code:

```
# coding: utf-8
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib2, re, os
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import simplejson as json

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3'

def fetchPage(url):
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    req.add_header('User-Agent', user_agent)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    html = response.read()
    response.close()
    return html

html = fetchPage("http://haukurhaf.net/json.txt")
jsonData = json.JSONDecoder().decode(html)
```

The JSON parser crashes with this error message: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 35: invalid continuation byte

Since I do not have any control over the server which holds the JSON data, I cannot control which encoding headers it sends out.  I'm hoping I can solve this on my end somehow.

Any ideas?

Comment: First thing to do is to figure out what the actual encoding is, since it isn't valid utf8. Can you retrieve the HTTP headers from the actual feed, and see if it specifies one?

Comment: That parses as valid JSON when I cut/paste.  You're probably having a problem with code pages.  Firefox says it ISO-8859-1.

Comment: (A simple way to find the code page is to open the link in Firefox, right-mouse-button in the screen, and select "View Page Info".  One of the values listed will be the "Encoding", which is what you need.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is encoded using Latin-1, not UTF-8, so you have to specify the encoding:

```
jsonData = json.JSONDecoder('latin1').decode(html)
```

BTW: `html` is a bad name for a JSON document...

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm.  Yeah, the HTML document I created was just so the error could be reproduced by someone else.

Answer (score 1):

> http://haukurhaf.net/json.txt

This resource is encoded as ISO-8859-1, or, more likely, the Windows variant code page 1252. It is *not* UTF-8.

You can read it with `response.read().decode('cp1252')` to get a Unicode string which `[simple]json` should also be able to parse.

However, in byte form, JSON must be encoded in a UTF. Therefore this is not valid JSON, and it will fail if you attempt to load it from a browser too.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make the string unicode first (it's latin-1 right now):

```
uhtml = html.decode("latin-1")
jdata = json.loads(uhtml)
```

Or, if `simplejson` doesn't have `loads`:

```
json.JSONDecoder().decode(uhtml)
```